# Properties of exponents when dealing with induction.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, exponentiation

This will most likely be a simple question for most of you. While watching my lecture today the white board cut out and the instructor didn't explain the final step in an example.

He went from $(3^{2^{i-1}})^2$ to $3^{2^i}$ without any explanation. What exponent property is that?

Comment: what is $a^b^c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general property is $(x^m)^n = x^{mn}$.

In this case,

$$\left(3^{2^{i-1}}\right)^2
 = 3^{2^{i-1}\cdot 2}
 = 3^{2^{(i-1)+1}}
 = 3^{2^i}.
$$

Comment: Ah! I was applying the outer exponent to the wrong part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that 
$$(a^b)^c=a^{b\cdot c}$$
and $$a^b\cdot a=a^{b+1} $$